# Help me identify, root, and install custom recovery my tablet

Tags: rooting, tablet

My friend gave a tablet. I want to root and tweak it so I can use it but after 6 hours of searching I gave up. How do I root this and find out what device this is?

After hours of surfing I ended up to this tablet models:

- WM8850-MID7038
- RS2906-MID7038
- (Touchmate) TM-MID730 - I tried the rooting process of this unit to my tablet, and I my tablet encountered boot-loop

I would like to know how to install a custom recovery and how to do the rooting process.

I installed an apps that gives system info:

```
OS
Browser UserAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-gb; MID Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30

Android ID : 145db405c08a059e

Uptime : 0 days, 0 hours, 19 minutes, 4 seconds

Uptime (without sleeps) : 0 days, 0 hours, 19 minutes, 4 seconds


Configuration
Font Scale : 1.3
Hard Keyboard Hidden : YES
Keyboard : NOKEYS
Keyboard Hidden : NO
Locale : en_GB
MCC : 0
MNC : 0
Navigation : NONAV
Navigation hidden : YES
Orientation : PORTRAIT
Screen Height DP : 1018
Screen Width DP : 640
Smallest Screen Width DP : 600
Screen Layout :
LONG_NO
SIZE_LARGE
SIZE_NORMAL
SIZE_SMALL
Touchscreen : FINGER
UI Mode :
NIGHT_NO
TYPE_NORMAL

BuildInfos
Android version : 4.4.4
Release Codename : REL
API LEVEL : 15
CPU ABI : armeabi-v7a
Manufacturer : unknown
Bootloader : unknown
CPU ABI2 : armeabi
Hardware : rk29board
Radio : unknown
Board : rk29sdk
Brand : Android
Device : rk2906
Display : IMM76D
Fingerprint : Android/rk2906/rk2906:4.0.4/IMM76D/20120620.094049:user/release-keys
Host : android-desktop
ID : IMM76D
Model : MID
Product : rk2906
Tags : release-keys
Type : user
User : android

Battery
Not charging...
Level : 35 %
Technology : Li-ion
Temperature : 0.0 âˆžC (32.0âˆžF)
Voltage : 3829 mV

Memory
Download Cache Max: 112MB/ Free: 108MB
data Max: 504MB/ Free: 395MB
External storage: mounted
External storage Max: 2.05GB/ Free: 812MB
External storage removable: true
External storage emulated: false
External SDCard Max: 0.93GB/ Free: 0.93GB
Total RAM: 333MB
Free RAM: 168MB
Threshold RAM: 40.47MB

Low Memory Killer Levels
FOREGROUND_APP:__ 14.35MB
VISIBLE_APP:_________ 19.41MB
SECONDARY_SERVER: 24.47MB
HIDDEN_APP:________ 32.47MB
CONTENT_PROVIDER: 40.47MB
EMPTY_APP:__________ 50.59MB

Telephony
Data Activity: DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE
Data State: DATA_DISCONNECTED
IMEI(or MEID): 355691453140520
IMEI/SoftVer: null
MSISDN: null
Registered MCC:
Registered MCC MNC:
Registered Operator Name:
Network Type: NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
Phone Type: PHONE_TYPE_NONE
SIM Country Code:
SIM MCC MNC:
SIM Operator Name:
SIM Serial Number: null
SIM State: SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN
Subscriber ID(IMSI): null
VoiceMail number: null
Roaming: false
No Cell detected

Networks
Background Data Usage: true


type mobile[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type WIFI[]
state CONNECTED/CONNECTED
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable true

type mobile_mms[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type mobile_supl[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type mobile_hipri[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type ETHERNET[]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type mobile_fota[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type mobile_ims[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type mobile_cbs[UNKNOWN]
state UNKNOWN/IDLE
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable false

type WIFI[]
state CONNECTED/CONNECTED
reason (unspecified)
extra (none)
roaming false
failover false
isAvailable true

Wifi
State: WIFI_STATE_ENABLED

Current access point: SSID: PLDTHOMEDSLEmArK, BSSID: 00:0e:f4:d5:a0:e2, MAC: 00:c3:51:75:ee:56, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, RSSI: -45, Link speed: 150, Net ID: 0, Explicit connect: false

DHCP info: ipaddr 192.168.1.4 gateway 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dns1 192.168.1.1 dns2 0.0.0.0 DHCP server 192.168.1.1 lease 86400 seconds

Last Scan:
0 SSID: PLDTHOMEDSLEmArK, BSSID: 00:0e:f4:d5:a0:e2, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS], level: -37, frequency: 2462

Configured Networks:
0 ID: 0 SSID: "PLDTHOMEDSLEmArK" BSSID: null PRIO: 1 KeyMgmt: WPA_PSK Protocols: WPA RSN AuthAlgorithms: PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP GroupCiphers: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP PSK: * eap: phase2: identity: anonymous_identity: password: client_cert: private_key: ca_cert: IP assignment: DHCP Proxy settings: NONE LinkAddresses: [192.168.1.4/24,] Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.1.1,] DnsAddresses: [192.168.1.1,]


CPU
Processor ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS 1007.45
Features swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3
CPU implementer 0x41
CPU architecture 7
CPU variant 0x3
CPU part 0xc08
CPU revision 2
Hardware RK29board
Revision 0000
Serial 0000000000000000
Frequency range: 408.0 -> 1008.0MHz
Current Frequency: 1008.0MHz
Frequency Stats (time):
- 408.0 MHz 89.6% (49795)
- 816.0 MHz 2.24% (1244)
- 1008.0 MHz 8.16% (4534)

Camera
As retreiving camera infos can give the impression that it is taking picture on some device, it is not enabled by default. If you wish to, go in settings menu.

Screen
Resolution: 480 x 764
Refresh Rate: 86.581
X factor for DIP: 0.75
Density: 120 dpi
Pixel per inch X: 131.94806 dpi Y: 143.43529 dpi

OpenGL
As retreiving opengl infos can crash some device, it is not enabled by default. If you wish to, go in settings menu.

Sensors
MMA8452Q 3-axis Accelerometer: 0.2 mA by Freescale Semiconductor
AK8975 3-axis Magnetic field sensor: 6.8 mA by Asahi Kasei
AK8975 Orientation sensor: 7.0 mA by Asahi Kasei
AL3006Proximity sensor: 0.5 mA by Dyna Image Corporation
AL3006 light sensor: 0.5 mA by Dyna Image Corporation

Environment
Root Directory: /system
Data Directory: /data
Download Cache Directory: /cache
External Storage State: mounted
External Storage Directory: /mnt/sdcard

Medias Directories
Alarms: /mnt/sdcard/Alarms
DCIM: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM
Downloads: /mnt/sdcard/Download
Movies: /mnt/sdcard/Movies
Music: /mnt/sdcard/Music
Notifications: /mnt/sdcard/Notifications
Pictures: /mnt/sdcard/Pictures
Podcasts: /mnt/sdcard/Podcasts
Ringtones: /mnt/sdcard/Ringtones

Features
android.hardware.wifi
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.nfc
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.screen.landscape
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.wifi.direct
android.hardware.usb.accessory
android.hardware.bluetooth
android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct
android.hardware.microphone
android.hardware.sensor.light
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.software.live_wallpaper
android.hardware.telephony
android.software.sip
android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand
android.hardware.usb.host
android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch
android.hardware.sensor.compass
android.hardware.faketouch
android.hardware.camera
android.software.sip.voip
android.hardware.sensor.proximity
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.telephony.gsm
android.hardware.telephony.cdma
android.hardware.camera.front
android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer
android.hardware.touchscreen
glEsVers=2.0

JavaProperties
java.vendor.url: http://www.android.com/
java.class.path: .
java.class.version: 50.0
os.version: 3.0.8+
java.vendor: The Android Project
user.dir: /
user.timezone: null
path.separator: :
os.name: Linux
os.arch: armv7l
line.separator:
file.separator: /
user.name:
java.version: 0
java.home: /system

Mount points
MountPoint
Name Type Options

- /
rootfs rootfs ro,relatime

- /dev
tmpfs tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755

- /dev/pts
devpts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600

- /proc
proc proc rw,relatime

- /sys
sysfs sysfs rw,relatime

- /acct
none cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct

- /mnt/asec
tmpfs tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000

- /mnt/obb
tmpfs tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000

- /dev/cpuctl
none cgroup rw,relatime,cpu

- /system
/dev/block/mtdblock8 ext3 ro,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=0,data=ordered

- /data
/dev/block/mtdblock6 ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,errors=continue ,barrier=0,data=ordered

- /cache
/dev/block/mtdblock5 ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,errors=continue ,barrier=0,data=ordered

- /sys/kernel/debug
/sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime

- /mnt/external_sd
/dev/block/vold/179:0 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime, uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utim e=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro

- /mnt/sdcard
/dev/block/vold/31:9 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime, uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utim e=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro

- /mnt/secure/asec
/dev/block/vold/31:9 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime, uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utim e=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro

- /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure
tmpfs tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000
```

Comment: Install king root
It will root yr phone vry fast n easily

Comment: You can try kingoo root it works with or without a pc i root or find a guide not on play store try 9 apps or apk pure

Answer (score 1):

As a can see it has a Rockchip CPU, you try root it with VROOT http://www.mgyun.com/en/getvroot . Rockchip sells the majority of it chips to chinese OEMs that's why its very likely that VROOT will do the job. Please try it and reply back :)

Comment: Sir it worked! Thank you very much! Can you please also help me regarding the installation of  custom recovery menu?

Comment: I think Custom Recovery Menu depends on device so I don't think I can help you with that. But keep in mind that the Custom Recovery Menu that you will install must be made specifically for your device. So DONT try to use a Custom Recovery Menu from other devices.

Comment: is there a way to identify my tablet specifically? model, brand, etc?

Comment: Maybe in the settings of the tablet, at the About Device senction?

Comment: Model Number: MID

That's all

Comment: So if you succeeded, it would be fair to add the needed steps to the answer and accept it as solution.